# OutOfMemoryError в Android приложении

Tags: java, android, json

Я посылаю запрос на сервер и получаю в ответ JSON и при попытке обработать эту строку приложение падает. Причем когда я делаю эту процедуру первый раз при запуске приложения все вроде бы норм, но если сделать эту процедуру повторно не выходя из приложения, то оно падает.
Пробовал вместо `String s` и `String line` применять `StringBuilder`, так как он не создает новые экземпляры но так, приложение начало падать вообще при первом запуске. Есть идеи как это исправить, может можно как то избежать использования 
`BufferedReader`  и как то по-другому обработать ответ?

```
public static List<Product> doGetAllSalemods() throws IOException {

    String url = "some_url";
    String result;

    httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    result = inputStreamToString(is);
    is.close();

    return createProductList(result);
}

private static List<Product> createProductList(String result) {

    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Product product = new Product();                
            product.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));                
            product.setAlias(jsonObject.getString("alias"));
            product.setIdCategory(jsonObject.getString("idCategory"));                
            product.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return productList;
}


private static String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String s = "";
    String line = "";
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {  // падает в этом месте
            s += line;  
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        rd.close();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: А ответ приходит большой? Сколько значений в JSON?

Comment: около 10,000 объектов JSON

Comment: Попробуй воспользоваться библиотекой GSON от гугла, и сразу перегонять JSON - ответ в объекты, возможно производительность позволит приложению не падать. Пример посмотри тут - http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/gson.php - или на их официальной странице

Comment: Зачем требуется такое количество данных сразу на месте в приложении? Лучше загружать понемногу, по мере надобности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в таких случаях json не целиком грузить, а стримить его. У того же GSON есть [streaming API](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming).

Comment: Протестировал GSON streaming, в результате: 
1) приложение перестало падать
2)тот же объем данных стал обрабатываться, примерно, в два раза дольше
3)объем потребляемой памяти остался на том же уровне.
Спасибо за помощь.